# Where can i find new bie guide to use this website

Tags: discussion

I am new to this website my friends suggest me this website, I am new to internet please guide me how to use this website.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to figure this out by reading our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) and by looking at how people ask questions.

If there is something specific you want to know, feel free to ask those types of questions in here on META where this types of questions belong.